# Proving that the map $(M+N)/N\to M/(M\cap N)$, $(m+n)+N \mapsto m+(M\cap N)$ is a linear isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

> $\textbf{1.}$ Let $M,N\subset L$. Prove that the following mapping is
>   a linear isomorphism : $$(M+N)/N\to M/(M\cap N)\, ; \quad (m+n)+N \mapsto m+(M\cap N).$$

I really have no idea in questions like this. The question is on kostrikin's book (*linear algebra and geometry*).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think it's generally contrary to MSE etiquette to express hatred for a book. In any case, the problem itself is perfectly reasonable if you've already been introduced to the idea of quotient spaces. What have you tried? Have you checked injectivity? Surjectivity? The expectation is that you include an attempt at any problem you ask for a solution to.

Comment: Also, consider learning [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Well written MathJax formulas are the standard on MSE and will help you learn to write neatly Texed homework that will delight future graders.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. This result is often called the [second isomorphism theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637798/second-isomorphism-theorem-for-subspaces). Do you already know the [first isomorphism theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932481/first-isomorphism-theorem-in-linear-algebra)?

Comment: A reasonable starting point would be to show that the proposed map is well-defined. That is, if $(m+n) + N = (m' + n') + N$, where $m,m' \in M$ and $n,n' \in N$, then $m + (M\cap N) = m' + (M\cap N)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave well-definedness and linearity to you to check. But, as an example, let's check injectivity.

Suppose $\phi(m_1 + n_1 + N) = \phi(m_2 + n_2 + N)$. Then $m_1 + M \cap N = m_2 + M \cap N$. Then $m_1 = m_2 + v$ where $v \in M \cap N$. We have
$$
m_1 + n_1 + N = m_2 + v + n_1 + N
$$
But, since $v + n_1, n_2 \in N$ we have $v+ n_1 + N = n_2 + N$. Hence
$$
m_1 + n_1 + N = m_2 + n_2 + N
$$
proving injectivity.

Note that if $L$ is finite dimensional, this suffices to prove surjectivity as well, so all there is left to check is well-definedness and linearity. Even if $L$ isn't finite dimensional, surjectivity follows almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first the map
$$
f\colon M\to (M+N)/N,\qquad f(x)=x+N
$$
This map is clearly surjective and its kernel is $M\cap N$. Thus the induced map
$$
g\colon M/(M\cap N)\to (M+N)/N,\qquad g(x+M\cap N)=x+N
$$
is an isomorphism.

Its inverse map is the one you are given.